# R Why the same number of observations is used when estimating ARIMA(1,0,0) and ARIMA(3,0,0)

Tags: r

I would expect as I add more lags the number of observations used to perform the estimation would decrease but its is not the case. Do you know how this works?

```
fit1 <- arima(presidents, c(1, 0, 0))
fit3 <- arima(presidents, c(3, 0, 0))

paste0("length fit1: ", length(fit1$residuals))
paste0("length fit3: ",length(fit3$residuals))
paste0("length presidents: ",length(presidents))

#  [1] "length fit1: 120"
#  [1] "length fit3: 120"
#  [1] "length presidents: 120"
```

**Update**

To see it clearly let's use another way to create the data. If I had to use another tool I would have done the following

```
a <- embed(presidents,3)  
b <- embed(presidents,2)  # setting the data for AR1 estimation
head(b)
paste0("nobs used to estimate AR1 is: ",nrow(b))


# :      [,1] [,2]
# : [1,]   87   NA
# : [2,]   82   87
# : [3,]   75   82
# : [4,]   63   75
# : [5,]   50   63
# : [6,]   43   50
# : [1] "nobs used to estimate AR1 is: 119"
```

Comment: Why would the number of observations decrease?

Comment: @Pascal updated the question

Comment: It is totally different algorithm, isn't it. So different algorithm, different behavior.

Comment: Granted, but I can't grasp what's happening under the hood.  I would expect that they would yield the similar results. For example `AIC( lm(b[,1] ~ b[,2]))`, and `AIC(fit1)`